# How was Fizeau able to measure interference fringes in his experiment of 1851?

Tags: interference, wavelength

I am wondering how [Fizeau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolyte_Fizeau), in the [famous experiment of 1851](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau_experiment), was able to measure changes in the interference fringes given that he used Sun light.

Sun light consists of all kinds of wave lengths and I feel that fringes should only have been visible if he had used a light source with a single (or at least a limited set of) wave length.

So, where am I wrong?

Comment: Sunlight does not exhibit coherence in time, but it does exhibit a high degree of coherence in space. That is, at one moment the sunlight *here* has the same phase as the sunlight *there*.